# How to use a loop to predict daily sales?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, prediction

I’m trying to predict sales for each of the remaining days before the close. I’m using linear regression to predict each individual day based on the previous 7-day average (among other factors). However, when the only remaining day is the close day, then I want to use a different function to predict that day. The model must also update the daily sales individually so that each prediction can be used for the next iteration.

Below is my attempt to write a loop that will continually predict each sale for each remaining day.

[Link to R Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wMCo.png)

```
### loop attempt
nnextdp <- DataforQuestion[c(74),]        #first na data point -- row 74, column Day6  for reference
   while (is.na(DataforQuestion[c(nnextdp),]) = TRUE) {      #while data point is NA, continue the loop
       if(nnextdp(head != Day0)) {Prior_week_average <- mean(nnextdp + right(7) - nnextdp) #set wkprioravg to the last 7 days of sales
          lmDayX <- lm(Day[right(head(nnextdp),1)] ~ Month + CDoW + 
           Prior_week_average, DataforQuestion)  #if datapoint is not in column Day0, let's use the lmDayX function
            predict(lmDayX, newdata = nnextdp)        #predict the data point's value & add it to the data set
                      nnextdp = nnextdp[c(-1)]                  #move the data point to the next na space
}   else if (nnextdp(head = Day0)) {Total_Not_Including_CSales <- aggreagate(Day1...Day203)  #if data point header is Day0, then sum the day1 - Day203 to get the total sales prior to close day
         lmDay0 <- lm(Day0 ~ Month + CDoW + Day1Sales + Total_Not_Including_CSales, DataforQuestion)  #if data point header is Day0, then run the other regression model
          predict(lmDay0, newdata = nnextdp)        #lmDay0 to predict the sales & fill in the value to the NA space
           nnextdp = nnextdp[c(-1)]  #move the data point to be predicted to the next NA space to the left of the previous
}  else
     print("complete")    #else print completed
}
```

Essentially I need the loop to predict the daily sales in columns Day0…...Day74 where there are NA values. But only where if there’s at least 7 preceding sales days of non-NA data.

I have provided a link to the dataset here.

[Link to dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uW1nEEmPyqsxQmBUGou_7HEAS04RlNK1)

I appreciate your help and please let me know if there’s something I can add to clarify anything!

Comment: you might want to write a function here which takes in input as the current day and output as your predicted sales. the conditions inside the functions are: if there are greater than 7 days of non NA data, predict else leave blank. you could split the dataset into many different rolling datasets using the `split` function. Once the splits are created, you could apply your function to it using `sapply`.

Comment: Great job adding the data. The picture you provided with the `r` code is hard to read. I suggest just posting the code in the question.

Comment: Definitely include code in the question, not as a picture. People want to be able to easily read your code and possibly copy/paste it. Questions that include a *little bit* of illustrative sample data in the question tend to get more help more quickly (not in an external link, and including just enough rows and columns to show the problem).

Comment: I have added the R code to the question to make it easier to read/recreate the error. Please continue to let me know if there's something I can do to make it easier to understand/solve the problem